# How can I check a uniqueidentifier is in a comma delimited list of ids?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to insert some records into a many to many table, the condition though is that a particular Id (uniqueidentifier) is in a comman seperated list of Id's (nvarchar).

I had thought it was working but it only seems to compare it to the first Id in the list?

How can I correctly use the list to insert the data as I expect.

Here is a snippet of my Sql:

```
 INSERT LineItemToSalesTax (SalesTax_Id, LineItem_Id) 
    SELECT  st.Id, li.LineItem_Id
    FROM    @LineItems li
            ,SalesTax st 
    WHERE   li.AppliedSalesTaxes IS NOT NULL
    AND     st.Id in (li.AppliedSalesTaxes)
```

li.AppliedSalesTaxes has a value in the following format:

`'C23E8882-A630-49B2-9E96-0313A4EC1C6A,3B96B6D4-85E7-4735-8351-1BD07FCFC395'`

I've tried a few scenarios and not quite got it working, I did spot a few articles that use Sql functions, but I would liket to avoid this if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the following CSV to ROWS function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CsvToRows
(
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS @ret TABLE 
(
    [Index] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Value NVARCHAR(500)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @pos INT,
            @i INT = 0,
            @piece NVARCHAR(500)

    IF RIGHT(RTRIM(@string),1) <> ','
    BEGIN
        SET @string = @string  + ','
    END

    SET @pos =  PATINDEX('%,%' , @string)
    WHILE @pos <> 0 
    BEGIN
        SET @piece = LEFT(@string, @pos-1)

        INSERT INTO @ret ([Index], Value)
        VALUES (@i, @piece)

        SET @string = STUFF(@string, 1, @pos, '')
        SET @pos =  PATINDEX('%,%', @string)
        SET @i = @i + 1
    END
    RETURN
END
```

So your query can become:

```
INSERT LineItemToSalesTax (SalesTax_Id, LineItem_Id) 
SELECT  st.Id, li.LineItem_Id
FROM    @LineItems li
       ,SalesTax st 
WHERE   li.AppliedSalesTaxes IS NOT NULL
AND     st.Id in (SELECT CAST(value as UNIQUEIDENTIFIER) FROM dbo.CsvToRows(t.AppliedSalesTaxes))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put the comma delimited GUID list into a table and then use that in your `IN` Operator:

```
-- get comma delimited list of GUIDs
declare @GUIDs nvarchar(369) -- 10 GUIDs and 9 commas
set @GUIDs = cast(newid() as varchar(36))
while len(@GUIDs) < 369
    begin
        set @GUIDs = @GUIDs + ',' + cast(newid() as varchar(36))
    end

-- put GUIDs in a table with dynamic sql
declare @GUIDTable table(ID uniqueidentifier)
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = 'select ''' + replace(@GUIDs,',',''' union select ''') + ''''
insert into @GUIDTable exec(@sql)
```

Then your code would be updated to:

```
INSERT LineItemToSalesTax (SalesTax_Id, LineItem_Id) 
    SELECT  st.Id, li.LineItem_Id
    FROM    @LineItems li
            ,SalesTax st 
WHERE   li.AppliedSalesTaxes IS NOT NULL
        AND     st.Id in (select ID from @GUIDTable)
```

Comment: hi ron, but that table would need to be recreated for every row in @LineItems right? How would that work?

Comment: Oh, I missed that bit. This solution is good for long lists of GUIDs, but if you are just comparing a GUID to a list if a few GUIDS, you could just use:
    where li.AppliedSalesTaxes like '%' + cast(st.Id as varchar(36)) + '%'

Answer (score 0):

This is not a very elegant solution but does get the job done in-line.

Replace the condition:

```
st.Id in (li.AppliedSalesTaxes)
```

with:

```
charindex('['+st.Id+']', '['+replace(li.AppliedSalesTaxes,',','][')+']') > 0
```